# Alterar linguagem do site com CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho um site em português e francês, criei duas pastas dentro de `application`, ficando assim.

```
application/language/portuguese-brazilian
application/language/french
```

Dentro dela coloquei os arquivos nas suas respectivas línguas.

Minha duvida é como alterar dinamicamente a língua do usuário baseado na URL que ele acessar. No momento estou setando a linguagem assim.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
     $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
     if ($lang == 'pt') {
      $this->lang->load(Array('nav_lang', 'buttons_lang'), 'portuguese-brazilian');
     }elseif ($lang == 'fr') {
      $this->lang->load(Array('nav_lang', 'buttons_lang'), 'french');
}
```

---

Eu precisava verificar se é de um domínio específico, por exemplo `dominio.com.fr` ele me redireciona para o francês ou `.br` pro português. Além disso que já fiz pela linguá do navegador

Comment: Não é só pegar o domínio acessado e fazer a condição tal fez com o cabeçalho? Não entendi exatamente qual é a sua dúvida.

Comment: A duvida esta em pegar o domínio. Eu tenho no config.php uma constante APP_URL que me a url dele, local ela é localhost/projeto, preciso de uma maneira de pegar somente o .br ou .fr para filtrar

Comment: E qual o valor em produção?

Comment: ainda não esta em produção, mas vai ser algo como dominio.com.br e dominio.com.fr

Comment: Então a pergunta resume-se a como extrair a última parte de uma *string* do tipo "dominio.com.br"?

Comment: Sim, não manjo de regex e não sei direito como ficaria com substring

Comment: Ou com um split pegando a 3 parte sei lá